# Nginx Spreadsheet Upload results in Bad Gateway

Tags: python, django, ubuntu, nginx

I have a Django application I'm working on and I want to upload a bunch of spreadsheets into it. However, I'm getting a bunch of 502 Bad Gateway errors inconsistently, which is blowing up my attempt to upload spreadsheets.

Is there something I can do to my nginx config to help it deal? I've been uploading spreadsheets in batches of 500, which I'm willing to do, but even those have been failing, and I have 85,000 entries total to upload. These are only 100kb files so I'm not sure what the problem is.

Here is my nginx config:

```
server {
        server_name http://mydomain;
        # define buffers, necessary for proper communication to prevent 502s
        proxy_buffer_size 128k;
        proxy_buffers 4 256k;
        proxy_busy_buffers_size 256k;

        client_max_body_size 4g;

        access_log off;

        location /static/ {
                alias /webapps/myapp/static/;
        }

        location / {
                proxy_pass http://127.0.0.1:8001;
                proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-Host $server_name;
                proxy_set_header X-Real-IP $remote_addr;
                add_header P3P 'CP="ALL DSP COR PSAa PSDa OUR NOR ONL UNI COM NAV"';
        }
}
```

If there are other configurations I should upload info for, please let me know. Thanks!

Comment: This has nothing to do with spread sheets! Please look at the nginx error log file and show the full stacktrace

Comment: Sure, where would I find that?

Comment: The location of the log files will be defined in the gunicorn configuration. Usually this is /var/log/gunicorn

Comment: Check your nginx error log /var/log/nginx/error.log

Comment: You might need to increase your `proxy_read_timeout`.